# Search match twice 2 keywords same column and copy result to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am stuck i don't know what code to use so i can search the same column twice for 2 different keyword and then copy data from the same row to another spreadsheet in sequence from a start cell. for details here's what i am trying to do.

1. **Limit the search** within a range of the worksheet (ex. Sheet 1 B1:N:200)
2. Search the **8th column (I)** of the limit range Sheet1 for keyword ("Goods")
3. Copy the data found in the **2nd (C) and 5th column (F)**  of same row where instance "Goods " is found
4. Paste Value of S**heet 1 - column 2 to Sheet2 - Column 3** (no format values only), and **Sheet 1 column 5 to Sheet 2 Column4** (with format and values) on a specific starting point (ex. Sheet 2 - B3) Next Match Result will be Sheet 2 - B4 and so on

5.**Search  AGAIN the 8th column of Sheet1** for keyword ("Services") starting from the top  (B1:N1)

6.Copy the data found in the **2nd (C) and 5th column (F)  of same row**  where instance "Services" is found

7. Paste Value of  S**heet 1 - column 2 to Sheet2 - Column 3** (no format values only), and **Sheet 1 column 5 to Sheet 2 Column4** (with format and values) to next row after the last PASTE from "Goods" was done. (ex last row match paste was C35 and D35 new found value should be paste in C36 a D36)
   Ending Output should be all "Goods" results first then "Services" results

I hope i have conveyed what i need clearly

I am trying to work on this code  that i found here but i just don't get how to insert the 2nd search loop for services., how to paste on specific cell in sheet2, how to follow the last row for services paste

```
        Sub CopyCells
    
    Dim lngLastRowSht1 As Long
    
    Dim lngLastRowSht2 As Long
    
    Dim counterSht1 As Long
    Dim counterSht2 As Long
    
    
    With Worksheets(1)
    
        lngLastRowSht1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    
        lngLastRowSht2 = Worksheets(2).Cells(Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    
            For counterSht1 = 1 To lngLastRowSht1
    
                For counterSht2 = 1 To lngLastRowSht2
    
                    If Sheets(1).Range("" & (counterSht1)).Value = "Goods" Then
    
                        Sheets(2).Range("B" & (counterSht2), "D" & (counterSht2)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C" & counterSht1, "D" & counterSht1).Value
    
                                        End If
    
                Next counterSht2
    
            Next counterSht1
    
            
    
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Edit1

As per request of sir Chris this is how it should look like

[image: Sheet]

[image: Sheet2]

Answer for this Query was best solved by @CDP1802 Worked as needed.

I learned that I needed 2 counters for it to work :) and I also learned how to properly label target destination.

Thank you for this community:)

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you can give some idea of what this would look like.  As far as I can tell, you don't even need VBA for this, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment the target row after each copy.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyCells()

    Const ROW_START = 3

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 as Long
    Dim keywords, word, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    keywords = Array("Goods", "Services")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)
    lastrow2 = ROW_START
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws1
        lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each word In keywords
            For r = 1 To lastrow1
                If Len(.Cells(r, "I")) = 0 Then
                    Exit For
                ElseIf .Cells(r, "I") = word Then
                    'Sht1 col 2 to Sht2 Col 3 (no format values only)
                    'Sht1 col 5 to Sht2 Col 4 (with format and values)
                    ws2.Cells(lastrow2, "C") = .Cells(r, "B")
                    ws2.Cells(lastrow2, "D") = .Cells(r, "E")
                    .Cells(r, "E").Copy
                    ws2.Cells(lastrow2, "D").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox r - 1 & " rows scanned " & vbLf & n & " rows copied", _
    vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```

Comment: SO GOOOD!! Worked Perfectly ! Liked that it has a prompt to say how many scanned and copy to check efficiency. I also liked how the code was made I understand the process per step with the data :) VERY MUCH THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Can I add a request how to make it stop if it encountered a blank cell no goods or services in column 8.

Comment: @jeremy is that a row with a keyword or any row ?

Comment: @CPD1802 Row with the keyword. Like the code you made will end only upon encounter of the blank cell in column I.

Comment: @jeremy OK see update

Comment: @CPD1802 Worked like a charm! Thank you again! I have another request to your code but I think its better to start another thread, Hope you can assist me again in the next thread.

Comment: Hi @CPD1802 I don't know what happened to you code but i just now noticed there is a little error, When  I ran your macro there is a prompt  together with the message box "Select Destination and Press Enter or choose Paste" sometimes if deletes some of my data because it overwrites where my current cell is or it hampers my next operation.

Seeking your advice again.

Comment: Found the solution Application.CutCopyMode = False :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make two routines: one for services and one for goods. But that code and the code above isn't very efficient.

Since Services & Goods are in the same column, try using the autofilter:

```
Sheets(2).UsedRange.autofilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("Goods", "Services"), VisibleDropDown:=False, Operator:=xlFilterValues
Sheets(2).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: I tried your code sir but it deletes my data but if it worked this would have been the simplest code to implement. Thank You

Comment: It does not delete the data. It filters it. You need to unfilter it. You can also change VisibleDropDown:=True